# Django Update unique modelform field

Tags: django

I have created small stock web app.

I created a stock model with unique `part_number` field. In my update template I send all item information to be displayed. Then I get an error in the `part_number` field that it is already there.

How can I avoid this validation for that part_number only?

I mean for same `part_number` suppose validation will not work. But if I modified to another `part_number` that already exists I get an error that it's being duplicated.

Model:

```py
class Stock(models.Model):
    part_number = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False, unique=True)   
    part_name = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(blank=False)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=3, blank=True)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True, null=True, default="")
    min_quantity = models.IntegerField(unique=False, blank=True, default=0)
    max_quantity = models.IntegerField(unique=False, blank=True, default=0)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['part_number']

    def clean(self):
        self.part_number = self.part_number.upper()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.part_number
```

Form.py:

```py
class StockUpdateModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
   
    class Meta:
        model = models.Stock
        fields = ['part_name', 'quantity', 'location','part_number']
```

views.py:

```py
def stock_update_form_view(request, part_id):    
    
    item = Stock.objects.get(id=part_id)
    item_id = Stock.objects.get(id=part_id).pk
   
    form = StockUpdateModelForm({
        'part_number' : item.part_number,
        'part_name' : item.part_name,
        'quantity' : item.quantity,
        'location' : item.location    
    })    

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = StockUpdateModelForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            s = Stock.objects.get(pk=item_id)
            s.part_name = form.cleaned_data['part_name']
            s.part_number = form.cleaned_data['part_number']
            s.quantity = form.cleaned_data['quantity']
            s.location = form.cleaned_data['location']
            print("form is valid")
            s.save()

            return redirect('/stock/')

    return render(request, 'stock/stock_update.html', {'form': form, 'pn': item.part_number})
```

html:

```html
<form class="bg-light shadow" method="POST">
       
        <div style="margin-left:10%; margin-top:30px">
            <h4>Part Number : {{ pn }}</h4>
        </div>
        <hr style="width:100%">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="row" style="margin-left:30px; margin-top:40px ">
            
            <div class="col-sm-4" style="margin-left:6%">
                {{ form.part_name|as_crispy_field }}
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4" style="margin-left:15%">
                {{ form.part_number|as_crispy_field }}
            </div>          
            <div class="col-sm-4" style="margin-left:6%">
                {{ form.quantity|as_crispy_field }}
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4" style="margin-left:15%">
                {{ form.location|as_crispy_field }}
            </div>
           
            
            <div class="col-sm-4" style="height: 100px; margin-top:30px ; margin-left:6%">
                <hr style="width:100%">
                <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Save"
                    style="width: 150px;">
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = StockUpdateModelForm(request.POST, instance=item)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
```

Comment: Thank you so much :)  I spent more than 2 full days searching for solution.